# Setting the Tag property of a VB6 menu object

Tags: menu, vb6

I have an old VB6 application that uses the `Tag` property to Enable / Disable the Main Menu items in the (startup) mdiForm. I see where the program reads the Menu Tag Property and compares it to the User's security (a string). If the Tag matches the User's security string then the menu item is made Visible and Enabled.

No where in the VB6 code or in the VB6 Menu Editor do I see how to initially set the `Tag` property for a menu item. The call to enable the User's menu items is the 5th line of code in the `MDIForm_Load()` event code, so there is not much else that can run before this call.

Does anybody know how to initially set the `Tag` property for a main menu drop down items?

Comment: make sure you have checked all the modules Also, there might be chance  it reads a value from Registry and assigns it to a variable then passes it on .tag;  does it have any DLL attached to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try clicking to select the menu item you are interested in, then the **Tag** property will be available in the properties window. You can also highlight the form that contains the menus in the project explorer and select the menu from the controls drop down.

[image]

Comment: JAC, I was too focused on the Menu Editor! Yes, when I used the Properties Window I found the mnuXXXX Report Items listed there. And yes there is a "TAG" property.